# How to substite a " in awk?

Tags: awk, quoting, escape-characters

For example, I need to change a `"` into the word `quote` in

to change

```
a string with a " at some point
```

into

```
a string with a quote at some point
```

I have tried:

```
$ echo 'a string with a " at some point' | awk 'sub(",quote)'
awk: cmd. line:1: sub(",quote)
awk: cmd. line:1:     ^ unterminated string
awk: cmd. line:1: sub(",quote)
awk: cmd. line:1:     ^ syntax error
$
$ echo 'a string with a " at some point' | awk 'sub(\",quote)'
awk: cmd. line:1: sub(\",quote)
awk: cmd. line:1:     ^ backslash not last character on line
awk: cmd. line:1: sub(\",quote)
awk: cmd. line:1:     ^ syntax error
```

whereas

```
$ echo 'a string with a " at some point' |
  awk 'sub("string","rope")'

=>

a rope with a " at some point
```

works for the string-rope word.

Comment: `echo 'a string with a " at some point' | awk 'sub("\"", "quote")'` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo 'duck " cat' | sed 's/"/quote/'
```

Or in `awk`, since `sub` takes a regular expression, mark it as such with the usual `//` form:

```
echo 'duck " cat' | awk 'sub(/"/,"quote")'
```

Comment: This is the easiest way to do it in awk. But for completeness, Wouter Verhelst's second awk example also works: `awk 'sub("\"", "quote")'`. And so too does llua's example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a string, you have to quote it. This is true for strings consisting of alphabetic characters (as you show in your string/rope example), but also for strings of metacharacters, like the double quote. In other words, `sub (","quote")` doesn't work for the same reason that `sub (q,"quote")` doesn't.

You need to ensure that your double quote is inside string terminators. This is made slightly more difficult because of the fact that you've already used the single quote as the string terminator in the shell to pass your program to `awk`, thereby making it harder to use it in your program. There are two ways to avoid that problem:

1. Rather than passing your program to `awk` as a string, write it to a file (let's say we call it `substitution.awk`), and then run `awk` with the `-f` parameter to point it to the file (i.e., `awk -f substition.awk`). This frees up the single quote as a string terminator, so that you can use it i  your program.
2. Both `awk` and your shell support the backslash (`\`) as an escape character. With it, you tell the shell or `awk` that it must not interpret the next character in the usual way, but that it must treat it as a regular character. In other words, you can do either this:

   ```
   awk 'sub(\'"\',"quote")'
   ```

   or this:

   ```
   awk 'sub("\"","quote")'
   ```

   In the first example, you escape two single quotes from the shell, so that `awk` sees them; in the second, you escape one double quote from `awk`, so that you build a string with a double quote in it.

Comment: The first awk example won't work, for two reasons. First, awk unlike Python doesn't recognize `'blah'` as a string. Strings have to be inside double quotes. Second, you can't escape single quotes inside single quotes in the way you're imagining. `'blah\'more'` isn't a single quoted string containing a single quote. Instead, the single quote after `blah` terminates the string. To escape single quotes from the shell, you have to instead do `'blah'\''more'`. The first single quote after `blah` terminates the single quoted string. Then `\'` gives the shell a single quote. Then a new string begins.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'a string with a " at some point' | awk -v dq=\" '{sub(dq,"quote")}1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use octal escape:

```css
awk 'sub("\42", "quote")' <<'eof'
a string with a " at some point
eof
```